# How to resume android camera preview after onPictureTaken function?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

I am developing an app that take pictures from camera object and save it to the sdcard. It works great except some things.(I cant config some parameters for example resolution). But when I take picture it freeze on the screen. I just want to resume the preview and capturing same way after I take picture. here is the full code : 
http://bahacanaydin.blogspot.com/2012/05/package-com.html

Answer (score 13):

You have to put `mCamera.startPreview();` inside your `onPictureTaken()` function to restart preview again, because it stops automatically when the picture is taken.

Comment: That's true. the preview starts again when I locate the mCamera.startPreview(); in onPictureTaken() function but I cant capture again , program force close

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help. From [Android SDK documentation on takePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29):

> After calling this method, you must not call startPreview() or take another picture until the JPEG callback has returned.

The JPEG callback is implementation of onPictureTaken(), as I understand. So you should defer your call to startPreview.

Answer (score 0):

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//Do something after 1000ms
       mCamera.startPreview();
           }
     }, 1000);
```